# Limitar el numero de envíos de un formulario

Tags: php, html, formularios, variables

Buenas tardes, no soy muy hábil en tema de programación, pero me manejo como puedo, mirando tutoriales, etc.

Tengo una pregunta que hacer a la comunidad:
Un cliente me ha pedido si podía hacer un formulario para su web donde como máximo se puedan enviar 30 formularios.
Para que lo entendais mejor, es un sistema de reserva de entradas y el maximo de entradas es de 30.

Estuve pensando como podía hacerlo y llegue a la conclusión que igual creando una variable con valor 30 y restando a cada envió -1 al llegar a 0 podría hacer que no se mostrara el formulario. Pero cuando me puse a hacerlo le vi el gran problema y es que yo declaraba la variable al principio: `$numentradas = 30` y luego al enviar el formulario le restaba 1, pero claro... al volver a refrescar la pagina volvía a ser 30 porque así estaba declarada la variable.

La verdad es que no se si hay alguna forma de declararla y a partir de que esta cambie mantenerla como ha quedado en el ultimo momento.

También estoy abierta a que me expliquéis una nueva forma quizás más fácil, o quizás más útil que me ayude a poder realizar lo.

**RESUMEN**: Quiero hacer un formulario en una pagina que solo se pueda enviar 30 veces en total, y después de estos 30 envíos hacer que desaparezca.

Actualmente los datos registrados en el formulario se guardan en una base de datos con un ID, por si sirve de ayuda para recomendarme otra forma de hacerlo.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Revisa [ask] para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta y obtengas excelentes respuestas, agrega un [mcve].

Comment: Podrias crear en la base de datos un campo en el cual registrarás cuantos formularios se han enviado. Por cada formulario enviado incrementarás en 1 el numero almacenado en la BD. Y antes de crear el formulario harías una comprobacion para ver si no se han llegado a los 30. No se si me expliqué.

Comment: Hola @OscarDíaz, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, entiendo que te refieres a que cree una columna con autoincrement, no? Como seria el codigo para comprobar este valor? O para no moelstar, como puedo buscarlo en el sr.google? muchas gracias

Comment: En lugar de usar un autoincrement, yo lo haria de manera "manual". Si al principio haces la comprobacion para saber si aun no se han alcanzado los 30 formularios, puedes guardar ese valor en una variable, y al terminar de insertar el formulario sumarle 1 a ese valor y guardarlo en la base de datos. Si no has realizado consultas a una BD antes te recomiendo que empieces por buscar las instrucciones basicas de MySql. Despues busca como hacer consultas con SELECT a una BD con php y mysql.

Comment: El tema es bastante mas complejo de lo que parece. Debes tener en cuenta la siguiente situación: quedan 5 entradas a la venta, y hay 10 personas en la página que dan a comprar al mismo tiempo. Como gestionarías esa situación? La solución a esta pregunta me temo que es demasiado amplia para el formato del sitio.

Comment: Hola @Pikoh, gracias por tu respuesta, pero la verdad es que es un local muy pequeñito que en principio no esta todo el mundo esperando como si se tratase de un concierto de Coldplay o asi, simplemente lo que no quiero es estar yo esperando a que se vendan.  Si se apunta mas gente y no hay mas entradas ya nos pondriamos en contacto pero como maximo pasaria con un par de entradas. No se como os lo haceis pero todo tipo de pregunta lo encontrais fatal aqui... solo estoy preguntado como lo hariais, no si es funcional o no..

Comment: Hola Berta. No, no encontramos fatal todo tipo de preguntas, sólo las preguntas que no se ajustan a las normas del sitio, que como ya te han indicado puedes consultar en [ask] y en el [help]. Un saludo.

Comment: Dicho eso,lo mas normal es que utilices una base de datos donde almacenes una fila por cada pedido de entradas con los datos de cada solicitud. Una vez lo montes así, un simple `SELECT COUNT...` te dará el numero de entradas vendidas, y lo comparas con el numero de entradas disponibles para saber si quedan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin poner el código ni la base de datos, es un poco complicado responderte, pero voy a hacerlo de manera teórica.

**Para Limitar el envio**

Dado que lo guardas en la base de datos, y quiere limitar a 30 correos, lo que podrías hacer es una consulta `AJAX` a tu base de datos, para saber si ya has enviado los 30 correos (`SELECT COUNT(0) FROM Tabla`), si es menor a 30 lo envías y sino muestras un mensaje.

Si ademas en la `BBDD`, guardas las entradas solicitadas, podrías hacer (`SELECT SUM(campo numero de entradas) FROM Tabla`), para ver si ya has vendido todo antes de enviar el formulario.

**Para cerrar el formulario**

Como supongo que no querrás modificar los enlaces siempre que se cierre un formulario, podrías hacer las mismas consultas de antes, al cargar la página, por `AJAX`, y en función del resultado, podrías mostrar un mensaje de página no operativa o el formulario